# JDK com.sun.tools not found after Maven install

Tags: java, windows, maven, jar, classnotfoundexception

My Problem (with *MAVEN*) just exist on Windows (not Linux) and not Inside the IDE (Eclipse)

Class:

```
    ...

    System.out.println("Location of Tools --> " + VirtualMachine.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());

    ...
```

Exception:

```
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine
                at my.package.bootstrap(Controller.java:37)
                at my.package.main(Main.java:35)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                ... 2 more
```

My Environment:

```
Windows: Windows 10 (Here are the Problems!!!)
Linux: Xubuntu 16.04 (Works fine)
Java: 8 oracle (not openjdk!)
Maven (**using the maven-assembly-plugin for installing**)
```

My Project Architecture:

```
My Project which using the com.sun.tools is a library: lib.jar
which gets used by Main Project: Main.jar.

I'm using maven to compile all of that into Main.jar
```

What works:

```
Linux Eclipse IDE: found
Linux - Shell: java -jar myjar.jar: found

Windows Eclipse IDE: found
--> Windows - Bash: /java_jdk_path/java -jar myjar.jar: _NOT_FOUND_
```

My *not*-working-solutions to make it find the lib on windows in main.jar:

```
set %JAVA_HOME%  ... to jdk
set %JRE_HOME% ... to jre
```

I found a lot of workarounds like i.e. maven profiles and so on, I tested all of them but nothing worked. One time 
I got it worked, when I copyed the com.sun.tools via maven plugin (mvn install...) into the JAR. Then it worked.

**But I need it to find the com.sun.tools dynamically - depending on the operating system linux and windows.**

Any suggestions for my next steps? I don't know what I could do that it works.
I always get this exception when using this tools.jar on windows after executing it with ...java -jar Main.jar

Goal: I want to start Main.jar (java -jar Main.jar) on any folder I want.

---

**UPDATE:
I added a sample Project, which fails for me exactly with this error.**

Just create a new Maven Project and add this to Main.java 
and to POM. Install it with: mvn install    and it fails.
Use the eclipse jar builder and it works!??? WTF Why?

Code:

```
    ...

    System.out.println("Location of Tools --> " + VirtualMachine.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());

    ...
```

POM:

```
    <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>C:\Output\</outputDirectory>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.test.Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: The com.sun.* classes jave never been part of the Java public API. They should not be used and are free to change or be removed at any time (and my not be even present in different vendors Java implementation).

Comment: IDE might be using a different Java runtime which is embedded inside its installation directory. Try executing your code using java executable in that location.

Comment: I added my goal which I want to do.

Comment: You need to handle that in your code via reflection, cause these classes do not exist on every JDK/JRE...

Comment: What I need is how to locate the tools.jar correctly via pom or s.th. like this, check the example plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its not the solution for the current problem, but I am using a workaround and I can recommend it to any other. I am using https://github.com/oshi/oshi now, because it has all the features what I need and wanted to get with that com.sun.tools.

But Anyway it would be nice to hear if anyone has a working solution for this maven install (maybe maven {java.home} bug?) problem.